# How to track downloads in iOS 6 Smart App Banner

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I want to add the iOS 6 Smart App Banner to our mobile web site to encourage downloads and app opens of our native app. How do I track the number of downloads from users who clicked through from the iOS 6 Smart App Banner?

Comment: Belkadam, I was asking how to track the downloads that came from the iOS 6 Smart App Banner, not how to add the banner. Here's a similar thread on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906502/is-it-possible-to-track-click-throughs-from-iphone-smart-banner

Answer (score -2):

Add this code on the head of your website:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=543714442" />
```

You have to replace the id number by yours