# Is it possible to use LinkShare signatures in an iOS Smart Banner?

Tags: ios, affiliate

We're using [Smart App Banners](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) to promote our iOS app, and we're passing Apple our `affiliate-data` so we can track how many people install our app via the banner.

But in normal iTunes LinkShare affiliate links, I'm able to pass in a "signature" parameter `u1` to my links, so I can e.g. run two ads, one with signature `u1=red` and another `u1=blue`, allowing me to see how many sales came from my red ad and how many came from my blue ad.

Is it possible to pass a signature parameter using Smart App Banners? If so, how?

Comment: I tried just appending `&u1=red` to the affiliate-data; that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links in an iTunes Smart App Banner are direct links to the iTunes store.

If you monitor the network traffic, you will see that the link into the store after you press on the Smart App Banner looks like this:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yelp/id284910350?mt=8&siteID=30&parnterId=12345

In order to use the "u1" value, your link has to run over the affiliate network - that link would look like this:

http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/stat?id=12345&offerid=146261&type=3&subid=0&tmpid=1826&RD_PARM1=https%253A%252F%252Fitunes.apple.com%252Fus%252Fapp%252Fyelp%252Fid284910350%253Fmt%253D8%2526partnerId%253D30&u1=red

The links do not track over the affiliate networks - so you are not able to append signature tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but in case anyone runs into the same issue, Itunes does offer an affiliate program through Performance Horizons Group (PHG).

https://itunes.phgconsole.performancehorizon.com/login/itunes/

They offer tracking with subids so using their links it would be possible to earn commissions on Itunes sales referred through your app AND track individual banners/campaigns with subids.